# Spring security https authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I'm using spring security 3.2.5 and Tomcat 7. When I try to enter a page (on a remote server over https) that needs authentication I'm not redirected to the default spring security login form.

my security.xml:

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/**"
            access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https"/>

        <security:port-mappings>
            <!-- Default ports -->
            <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="443" />
        </security:port-mappings>
```

The error I'm getting :

```
Google Chrome's connection attempt to X.X.XXX.42 was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I tried to follow this tutorial: [Link](http://myshittycode.com/category/spring/spring-security/)

Blockquote

Comment: Have you enabled the https connector in server.xml? Is port 443 opend in firewall?

Comment: Yes. the https works the redirection does not

Comment: Are you able to access the login page through http?

Comment: No, I'm using a load balancer but if i try directly to the tomcat yes

Answer (score 0):

You say (in the comments) that you can reach the login page **directly** using HTTPS, but when you try it **throught the load balancer**, you hit the error.

I believe you have to configure not only the tomcat to work with HTTPS, but also the load balancer. If you work with F5, [this link](https://support.f5.com/kb/en-us/products/big-ip_ltm/manuals/product/ltm_implementation/sol_http_ssl.html) might be helpful.

(As a side note, the tagging of this question should change from "spring security" to "load balancer" etc...)